# Applications running under SELinux that access NonPosix drives

Tags: selinux

I am looking to use either AppArmor or SELinux. Of what I've seen so far I think I prefer SELinux, but there is one thing that does concern me, that is accessing NonPosix partitions.

Let us look at a specific exmple: Suppose I want okular to read and write ( and only to read and write ) from an sdcard which is likely formatted in FAT32.

Is there some work around or some policy that will allow me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

> The -o context= option is useful when mounting file systems that do not support extended attributes, such as a floppy or hard disk formatted with VFAT, or systems that are not normally running under SELinux, such as an ext3 formatted disk from a non-SELinux workstation. You can also use -o context= on file systems you do not trust, such as a floppy.

It's from SELinux manual http://www.centos.org/docs/4/html/rhel-selg-en-4/rhlcommon-section-0019.html .
Would that seem helpful for you?